# Definite Integral of $(\sin x)^2\cos x$ from $\pi/2$ to $-\pi/2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can someone show me the steps to solve the following Finite Integral?

$$\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^2x\cos x \,dx$$

I know you can solve it by doing $u$-substitution with $\sin x$, but I must be doing something wrong in the last steps since I don't get the desired result, which is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Notice that $\sin^{2}(x)\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x = \sin^{2}(x)\mathrm{d}(\sin(x))$

Answer (score 2):

Set $\sin x=u$

$$\int_{-1}^1u^2du=(u^3/3)|_{-1}^1=?$$

Comment: I got to that, but when I plug sinx and try to solve it, I don't get 2/3, but another weird number

Comment: @Nello 1 cubed divided by 3 is 1/3. -1 cubed divided by 3 is -1/3. 1/3 minus -1/3 is 2/3.

Comment: There is no more $\sin x$. Everything is in terms of $u$. That’s why you transform the limits of integration as well.